# Fill Bounding Boxes in 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bounding-box, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D numpy array which looks like

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]) `
```

I want to create bounding box like masks over the 1s shown above. For example it should look like this

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], 
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

How can I do it it easily? Also how do I do it if other no.s like 2,3 etc exist but I want to ignore them and the groups are mostly 2.

Comment: search "connected component labeling" to learn how to identify separate objects amidst a field of a "background" value. Then find min and max row / col of each unique label.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We have `skimage.measure` to make life easy when it comes to component labeling. We can use [`skimage.measure.label`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) to label the different components in the array, and [`skimage.measure.regionprops`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops) to obtain the corresponding slices, which we can use to set the values to `1` in this case:

```
def fill_bounding_boxes(x):
    l = label(x)
    for s in regionprops(l):
        x[s.slice] = 1
    return x
```

---

If we try with the proposed example:

```
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops

a = np.array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

We get:

```
fill_bounding_boxes(x)

array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 6):

While the previous responses are perfectly fine, here's how you could do it with `scipy.ndimage`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

def fill_bboxes(x):
    x_components, _ = ndimage.measurements.label(x, np.ones((3, 3)))
    bboxes = ndimage.measurements.find_objects(x_components)

    for bbox in bboxes:
        x[bbox] = 1

    return x
```

`ndimage.measurements.label` does a connected component labelling with the 3x3-"ones" matrix defining the neighbourhood. `find_objects` then determines the bounding box for each component, which you can then use to set everything within to 1.

Comment: do you think you can extend it for non-orthogonal bounding box as well.

Comment: You could determine the minimum enclosing rectangle for each object (i.e. for each ```bbox in bboxes``` and then fill the area under that rectangle instead of the area under bbox. As far as I know, scipy doesnt have a premade function for this. So either you write it yourself or you use something like OpenCVs ```cv.minAreaRect```, but in either case, you have to decide how to discretize when filling.

Answer (score 4):

**There is one solution**, but its a little bit hacky and I will not program it for you.

OpenCV - Image processing library, has a algorithm for finding Rectangular contour -> Straight or Rotated. What you may want to do is to transform your array into 2D grayscale image, find contours and write inside the contours your 1s.

Check this image - it is from Opencv DOC - **7.a** - https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

[image]

You would be interested in everything that is inside green lines.

---

To be honest, I think seems to me much easier than programming some algorithm for bounding boxes

**Note**

Of course you dont really need to do the image stuff, but I think it is enough to use opencv's algorithm for the bounding boxes(countours)

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem. A 2D convolution is a natural approach. However, if the input matrix is sparse (as it appears in your example), this can be costly. For sparse matrix, another approach is to use a clustering algorithm. This extracts only the non-zero pixels from the input box a (the array in your example), and runs a hierarchical clustering. The clustering is based on a special distance matrix (a tuple). Merging happens if boxes are separated by a max of 1 pixel in either direction. You can also apply filter for any numbers you need in the initialization step (say only do for a[row, col]==1 and skip any other numbers, or whatever you wish.

```
from collections import namedtuple 

Point = namedtuple("Point",["x","y"]) # a pixel on the matrix
Box = namedtuple("Box",["tl","br"]) # a box defined by top-lef/bottom-right

def initialize(a):
    """ create a separate bounding box at each non-zero pixel. """
    boxes = []
    rows, cols = a.shape
    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            if a[row, col] != 0:
                boxes.append(Box(Point(row, col),Point(row, col)))
    return boxes

def dist(box1, box2):
    """ dist between boxes is from top-left to bottom-right, or reverse. """
    x = min(abs(box1.br.x - box2.tl.x), abs(box1.tl.x - box2.br.x))
    y = min(abs(box1.br.y - box2.tl.y), abs(box1.tl.y - box2.br.y))
    return x, y

def merge(boxes, i, j):
    """ pop the boxes at the indices, merge and put back at the end. """
    if i == j:
        return

    if i >= len(boxes) or j >= len(boxes):
        return

    ii = min(i, j)
    jj = max(i, j)
    box_i = boxes[ii]
    box_j = boxes[jj]
    x, y = dist(box_i, box_j)

    if x < 2 or y < 2:
        tl = Point(min(box_i.tl.x, box_j.tl.x),min(box_i.tl.y, box_j.tl.y))
        br = Point(max(box_i.br.x, box_j.br.x),max(box_i.br.y, box_j.br.y))
        del boxes[ii]
        del boxes[jj-1]
        boxes.append(Box(tl, br))


def cluster(a, max_iter=100):
    """ 
        initialize the cluster. then loop through the length and merge 
        boxes. break if `max_iter` reached or no change in length.
    """
    boxes = initialize(a)
    n = len(boxes)
    k = 0

    while k < max_iter:
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                merge(boxes, i, j)
        if n == len(boxes):
            break
        n = len(boxes)
        k = k+1

    return boxes

cluster(a)
# output: [Box(tl=Point(x=2, y=2), br=Point(x=5, y=4)),Box(tl=Point(x=11, y=9), br=Point(x=14, y=11))]

# performance 275 µs ± 887 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# compares to 637 µs ± 9.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each) for 
#the method based on 2D convolution
```

This returns a list of boxes defined by the corner points (top-left and bottom-right). Here x is the row number and y is the column numbers. The initialization loops through the entire matrix. But after that we only process a very small subset of points. By changing the dist function, you can customize the box definition (overlapping, non-overlapping etc). Performance can further be optimized (for e.g. breaking if i or j greater the length of boxes within the for loops, than simply returning from the merge function and continue).