# Fill in overlapping bounding boxes in 2d Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, geometry

I have a binary 2D Numpy array with potentially overlapping bounding boxes that I'd like to fill in. I've attached a figure to illustrate my problem. The input is on the left, and the ideal output is on the right. I've tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638817/fill-bounding-boxes-in-2d-array), which outputs the subfigure in the center, which does not suit my purposes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Direct fill-hole tool with SciPy : [`scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes.html)
 -

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_fill_holes

# Read in image as grayscale and assuming blobs are at 255 and background at 0
im = cv2.imread('boxes.png',0)

cv2.imwrite('out.png', (binary_fill_holes(im)*255).astype(np.uint8))
```

**Approach #2 :** Floodfill at one corner (that is background with `0`) with `255`. So, all of background is now `255`. Invert it to get inner regions at 255, but this will set the inner box intersection lines at 0. So, `OR` it with the original image to get our desired output. Hence, implementation would look something along these lines -

```
from skimage.segmentation import flood_fill

filled = flood_fill(im.copy(), (0, 0), 255)
mask = (filled==0) | (im==255)
cv2.imwrite('out.png', (255*mask).astype(np.uint8))
```

Or use `im` data :

```
im[mask] = 255
cv2.imwrite('out.png', im)
```

Input ('boxes.png') :

[image]

Output ('out.png') :

[image]