# How to read a dataframe from an excel sheet containing multiple tables?

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel sheet which contains multiple tables, each with different column names.
The image below shows how the tables are present in the sheet :

[image]

If I want to read the summary table into a pandas dataframe how to do it other than manually specifying the row and column values to be read?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367805/pandas-read-excel-multiple-tables-on-the-same-sheet) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with [scikit-image](/questions/tagged/scikit-image) (*highly inspired by @Roshan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63499785/16120011)*) :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
​
#pip install scikit-image
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
​
df = pd.read_excel("wbook.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1", header=None)
​
larr = label(np.array(df.notnull()).astype("int"))
​
list_dfs = []

for s in regionprops(larr):
    sub_df = (df.iloc[s.bbox[0]:s.bbox[2], s.bbox[1]:s.bbox[3]]
                .pipe(lambda df_: df_.rename(columns=df_.iloc[0])
                .drop(df_.index[0])))

    list_dfs.append(sub_df)
```

Output :

```
  col1 col2 # <- first DataFrame
2    1   aa
3    2   bb <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

  col3 col4 # <- second DataFrame
7    3   cc
8    4   dd <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

   col5 col6 # <- third DataFrame
9     5   ee
10    6   ff <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

*Spreadsheet used :*

[image]

**NB** : The range of values (*aka* tables) in the spreadsheet​ doesn't need to have the same shape.